# building a brick pyramid

Tags: java

The problem I'm trying to solve is building a pyramid centered in the window built with individual bricks. With the code blow I expect the there should be 1 brick on the 1st row, two bricks on the 2nd row, 3 on the 3rd row all the way up to 12 bricks on the base of the pyramid. Instead only 1 brick is appearing in the center of the screen. What could I do to correct my code?

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;



public class BrickPyramid extends GraphicsProgram{          

        public void run() {
         /** xBrick, yBrick trying to calculate for the center of the window **/ 

         double xBrick = (getWidth() - BRICK_WIDTH) / 2 ;              
         double yBrick = (getHeight() - BRICK_HEIGHT) /2 ; 

         /** getting the size of the brick by multiplying the brick width by brick height **/ 
         double buildingBrick = BRICK_WIDTH * BRICK_HEIGHT; 

           for (int i = 0 ; i <= 12; i ++ ){
               for (int j = 0; j < BRICKS_IN_BASE; j++){

                   double x = i * buildingBrick; 
                   double y = j * buildingBrick; 


               /* adding the brick with starting point xbrick, ybrick **/
                   GRect brick = new GRect (xBrick, yBrick, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
                   add(brick);

               } 
           }

    }
private static final int  BRICK_WIDTH = 100;
private static final int  BRICK_HEIGHT = 50;
private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 12;
}
```

Comment: @twall how do i do that?

Comment: @twall no. The homework tag is deprecated. If I see it appear here, I will remove it.

Comment: sorry, i missed that one. never mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You construct all of your bricks with this line executed many times:

```
GRect brick = new GRect (xBrick, yBrick, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
```

but you never change the values of any of the variables passed to the constructor so the bricks are all drawn in the same place.

You need to change these values for each brick. Maybe use i and j to determine those values?

Comment: I'm completely stumped with the solution to this problem. Do I need to change the value for the placement of each brick?

Comment: Yes, the values passed to new GRect() are the x coordinate, y coordinate, width and height of the brick.  The width and height are the same for each brick, but the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate will change.  In fact, they'll each be a function of variables i and j.  The question you need to answer are what are those functions - how do you figure out the coordinates for a brick given i and j where i appears to be the row and j appears to be the brick number in that row.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to take some time and think this one out and see if I can figure out the solution.

Comment: I'm really stuck on the problem. I'm trying to set the values of x and y for the GRect as x = one centered brick and y = one centered brick...for the first row. Then x = two centered bricks and y = two centered bricks for the 2nd row. Then x = three centered bricks and y = 3 centered bricks. Do I create a new variable and set the value of that new variable as centered brick * i for the x and one centered brick * j for the y? Would that be the correct strategy?

Comment: What's the y-coordinate for any brick in row 1? row 2? row 3? From those values can you come up with a formula for the y-coordinate of the nth row?

Comment: I'm experimenting with something and I think I might be on to something. Thanks. I'm going to see if I can crack the answer.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you are still looking for an answer but this code does the job:

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {

private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

```
private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

public void run() {

    double xBrick = (getWidth() - BRICK_WIDTH) / 2 ;              
    double yBrick = (getHeight() - BRICK_HEIGHT) /2 ; 

    for (int n=1;n<15;n++){
       for (int m=0;m<=n-1;m++){

        GRect Brick =new GRect(xBrick-(BRICK_WIDTH*(n-1))/2+m*BRICK_WIDTH,yBrick+BRICK_HEIGHT*(n-1),BRICK_WIDTH,BRICK_HEIGHT);
        add(Brick);

        }
      }
}
```

}